# Collaborative training possible in ml5.js or Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, ml5.js

I would like to build an image classifier with ml5.js or Tensorflow.js. I want the user to be able to add their own labels, ie. train the model. Daniel Shiffman's tutorial in transfer learning is excellent for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRpZ5OqUY6Y

However, I would want several users to be able to train the same model. People would contribute to the same model with their own classifications.

Ideally one participant could contribute from their own browser in country X and other in country Y. Or, at least, two users in the same space doing the labeling from their own browsers. Displayed images would probably come from a JSON file.

I have tested Socket.io for collaborative mouse drawing using p5.js, but that's basically all my relevant experience in this kind of collaborative apps. So: is it possible for multiple users to train the same ml5.js/Tensorflow.js model using Socket.io or something similar?

Warm thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I once used [TogetherJS](https://togetherjs.com/) from Mozilla in a simple way to collaboratively add to the training dataset across any number of browsers. But each instance needed to run tf.fit on the extended dataset. [Federated Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_learning) would be the next step to avoid all this redundant computation.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for sharing this! I have also had thoughts about using Python; however, the collaboration part still needs to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need real time collaboration for this? The users can supply images and labels from their browsers and press an `upload` button.

There can be a `train` button in the client that tells the server to start training again. The model is only on the server so everyone can contribute to it.

While the server is training and it receives a new `train` command, it will just send back a message `already in training process`.

This way you won't need socket.io...